# Drupal stripping my closing div tags from a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, drupal

I'm trying to style a Google Maps InfoWindow. For each of my map markers I have a window that works perfectly on a local site and in a JSFiddle. However, when I add the code to a Drupal block, it strips the closing div tags.

I've tried this way:

```
`var message = 
"<div class='window-container'>" +
  "<div class='window-content'>" +
    "<div class='window-header'>" +
      "<div class='window-title'>" + name + "</div>" +
      "<div class='window-subtitle'>" + org + "</div>" +
    "</div>" +
    "<div class='window-body'>" + summary + "...</div>" + 
  "</div>" +
"</div>";`
```

And this way:

```
`var message =
'<div class="window-container">\
  <div class="window-content">\
    <div class="window-header">\
      <div class="window-title">' +name+ '</div>\
      <div class="window-subtitle">' +org+ '</div>\
    </div>\
    <div class="window-body">' +summary+ '</div>\
  </div>\
</div>';`
```

And this way with a Babel compiler:

```
`var message = '
  <div class="window-container">
    <div class="window-content">
      <div class="window-header">
        <div class="window-title">${name}</div>
        <div class="window-subtitle">${org}</div>
      </div>
      <div class="window-body">${summary}</div>
    </div>
  </div>'`
```

And on the page, in my console, it always comes out like this!

```
`var message = 
"<div class='window-container'>" +
  "<div class='window-content'>" +
    "<div class='window-header'>" +
      "<div class='window-title'>" + name + "" +
      "<div class='window-subtitle'>" + org + "" +
    "" +
    "<div class='window-body'>" + summary + "..." + 
  "" +
"";`
```

It removes all the closing div tags! Why?

Comment: "when I add the code to a Drupal block" to clarify are you adding this trough a wysywig editor? if so you probably should take a look at your text filters it will likely say that it will strip broken html and/or incomplete html  or something like that and somehow it sees your html as broken

Comment: Unchecking the filter to "Correct faulty and chopped off HTML" solved my problem. Thank you @melvin!

Answer (score 0):

If you paste your code into ckeditor or other filters you'll have some trouble like that.

So it's recommanded to create a custom block programmatically, like explained here :
https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-blocks/create-a-custom-block

Comment: This link is dead, can you update it?

Comment: @Sean done ! ;)